# How can I retrieve number of times an entry has been updated since postDate

Tags: templating

For a news site I would like to retrieve the number of times an entry has been updated since postDate. Is that possible without using a plugin? Im using craft pro and have versioning enabled for that section.

Answer (score 1):

Update: This came up in [another question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/how-can-i-display-entry-edit-history-on-the-front-end) and I think that I may have found a simple way to do this without the use of a plugin.

```
{% set versions = craft.entryRevisions.getVersionsByEntryId(entry.id, entry.locale) %}
{{ versions|length }}
```

Comment: Thank you Douglas, but im not very familiar with plugin development yet. Maybe this will turn up in the feature releases of craft. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @imnotsure have a go at installing the businesslogic plugin. Then just paste the above code into the variables file. It's really very easy. And I think that you'll soon find that every project requires at least some small business logic that is best served with a small plugin. And if you have a questions, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Ill give it a try. Thanks for the code example!